# render the view then call the existing AJAX view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I don't know how I am going to ask or start my question but what I want is to reuse my AJAX view to other page. I have an existing AJAX view, when I click a link from my sidebar I want to render a new page then call the AJAX view.

Please see example code below. I hope you understand my problem.

## items_controller.rb

```
def index
    @items = Item.all
end
```

## others_controller.rb

```
def category
    @categories = Category.all
end
```

## views/items/index.html.erb

```
<%= @items.count %>
<div class="ajax_form"></div>
```

## views/others/category.js.erb

```
$(".ajax_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'category') %>");
```

## views/others/category.html.erb

```
<%= @categories.count %>
```

After I click the link from the sidebar, I want to call the ajax also without recreating it.

```
<a href="<%= items_path %>" >
  click_me
</a>
```

Comment: Do you want that on click of click_me link request is sent to both index action of items controller and an ajax request is sent to category action of others controller ?

Comment: @Prity.. yes.. I want to call both.. or if not possible I can put the method of category to item method, but still I want to display the ajax to the view of `items/index.html.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by sending an extra parameter like this:

```
<a href="<%= items_path %>?fetch_category=true" >
  click_me
</a>
```

Change your index action of items controller

```
def index
    @items = Item.all
    @fetch_categories = params[:fetch_category] unless params[:fetch_category].blank?
end
```

And finally in your views/items/index.html.erb add these lines at the bottom of file.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
     <% if @fetch_categories %>
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= others_category_path %>",
        type: "GET",
        data: {}
      });
    <% end %>
  });
</script>
```